# Retrofit POST method returns error 400

Tags: android, retrofit

I would like to call a POST Method(Django REST framework) in Retrofit with a  For that, I call as follow from the postman and works fine for me.

[image: postman]
I have done the Android part as follows:

API INTERFACES:

```
public interface SOService {

   @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api-auth/")
Call<Tokken> get_tokken(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);

}
```

APIUtility class as

```
public class ApiUtils {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/";

    public static SOService getSOService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(SOService.class);
    }
}
```

RetrofitClient as :

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {

        OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();



        if (retrofit==null) {


            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(clientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

And finally, call the function as following

```
private void signIn() {
    boolean isValid = validate();
    if (isValid) {

        mService.get_tokken(user.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<Tokken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Tokken> call, Response<Tokken> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    System.out.println("Te lo imprimo");
                    System.out.println(response.body().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "tokken recibido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    // handle request errors depending on status code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Tokken> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error al recibir tokken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

            }
        });
        /*startActivity(new Intent(this, RolSelection.class));*/
    }
}
```

And the final result is always the same, I get this message in the server:

> [17/Apr/2018 01:12:33] "POST /api-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52

But in Android  I get this:

> I/System.out: Te lo imprimo
>                 Tokken{tokken='null'}

Any idea why the tokken is null? When I use postman I get a result.

UPDATE with the Tokken class:

```
public class Tokken {

    @SerializedName("tokken")
    @Expose
    private String tokken;

    public String getTokken() {
        return tokken;
    }

    public void setTokken(String tokken) {
        this.tokken = tokken;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tokken{" +
                "tokken='" + tokken + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: post the Token class too…?

Comment: Tokken class added!

Comment: Seems like you’re missing `.client(clientBuilder.build())` in your retrofit, can you add that and check again? the rest appears to look ok. You don’t need either `@SerializedName("tokken”)` or `@Expose` since your field’s name is `tokken` same as JSON.

Comment: Edited it withe the .client(clientBuilder.build()), but the results are the same, I get a null tokken object

Comment: We’re going to need more information here. Add the Log interceptor to your HTTP instance and log the entire payload / response. If you have Charles Proxy, it’s very helpful to use during API development to inspect what goes back and forth between your Client/Server. "method returns error 400” is not seen anywhere in your posted log, so the “null” token you get is a side-effect.

Comment: Wait, I just realized… you’re using `SerializedName` to `TOKKEN` whereas your JSON is `token`. That’s why it’s null. You’re serializing to nothing. Change the line the `SerializedName` to `@SerializedName("token”)`

Comment: @MartinMarconcini sorry man, I caught it first :)

Comment: No worries @Kulebin You need the rep more than I do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: change field name in Tokken class from `@SerializedName("tokken")` into `@SerializedName("token")` as on attached screenshot from Postman in response you get `"token"` key but not `"tokken"`.

Maybe it's not the root cause but one of the problem for sure:
you didn't configure your retrofit client properly, you missed to add http client:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(clientBuilder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Comment: Edited withe .client(clientBuilder.build()), but the results are the same

Comment: @Green_Sam I've noticed that on provided screenshot and in your code snippet you use different localhost ip in `BASE_URL`. Are you sure that you send a request to the same server instance?

Comment: Yes, I'm using android emulator, that's the ip for the localhost of the machine

Comment: @Green_Sam Also check spelling of `@SerializedName("tokken")`, I think the 2nd 'k' is redundant

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your bean object (`Token`) has a GSON annotation to serialize as `tokken`.

if you change your `@SerializedName("tokken”)` to `@SerializedName("token”)`, and assuming the request has no other problems, that should correctly deserialize.

I don’t know why you call it `tokken` in one side and `token` in another, but I would avoid it if possible, unless you’re planning on adding unit test to ensure *future you* doesn’t forget about this.

Another way to pass a Body (which may be easier, depending…) is to use a HashMap:

```
@POST("/api-auth/“) 
Call<Tokken> get_tokken(@Body HashMap<String, Object> body);
```

Then you can pass a map containing:

```
[“username”, “YourUsername”],
[“password”, “YourPassword”]
```

But without extra logging (or a proxy in-between to see what is actually going on), it’s very hard to debug.

Remember that your question’s title is "Retrofit POST method returns error 400”. But your token being null is a side-effect of your API returning 400 error. 400 Error is “BAD REQUEST”, so something is not what your server expects.

**nitpick**: I’d rename your API method to `getToken(…)` or `fetchToken(…)` to be more Java/Kotlin/Android friendly and also more self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes

1. change `tokken` to `token`

```java
@SerializedName("tokken")
@Expose
private String tokken;
```

to

```java
@SerializedName("token")
@Expose
private String tokken;
```

2. remove the extra  `\`  in `SOService`, it should be

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api-auth/")
```